# jQuery append table in loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an $.each in jquery and in this each statement I am trying to append to a table:

```
$.each(result, function (y, z) {

                $table.append("<tr>");

                $table.append("<td>" + y + "</td>");

                $table.append("</tr>");

            });
```

But I am getting weird results like so:

```
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</tbody>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>ccc</td>
<td>ddd</td>
```

I am expecting

```
<tr>
<td>aaa</td>
<td>bbb</td>
<td>ccc</td>
<td>ddd</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can't append start and end tags separately. You're not appending HTML, you're appending DOM elements. `$table.append("<tr><td>" + y + "</td></tr>")`

Comment: jQuery appending doesn't work like concatenating text, you have to append whole elements.  Append the `td` to the `tr` and then the `tr` to the `table`.  Or do it all at once like @JJJ suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code, you trying to add html with `append` without jQuery object and secondly not appending in correct way.

```
$.each(result, function (y, z) {

  $table.append($("<tr><td>" + y + "</td></tr>"));

});
```

Or,

```
$.each(result, function (y, z) {

 var row = "<tr>"
 row += "<td>" + y + "</td>";
 row += "</tr>";

 $table.append($(row));

});
```